# directory issues with an argument parser (ipython)

Tags: ipython, argparse

## import the necessary packages

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
```

*# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments*

```
**ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())**
```

*# load the image and show it*

```
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
cv2.imshow("image", image)**
```

My error is:

```
usage: -c [-h] -i IMAGE
-c: error: argument **-i/--image is required**
```

If this is my current wd: C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\IPython Notebooks

what is wrong? what should I be inputing for -i/--image?

Comment: What are giving it that produces the error?  I expect to see something like `-i ~/dir/image.png`.  That is, a file name after the `-i` or `--image` flag.